# asp.net identity , connecting more tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In ASP.NET identity

`AspNetUsers` table `id` column

I create another table name `Staff`

I link both tables with `AspNetUsers` `id` to Staff table column `Staff_ID`

> (both tables are nvarchar(128))

I CRUD the Staff in visual studio

When I create the new record, in `Staff_ID` field, it shows me the complete list of users in `AspNetUser` in a drop-down list.

I don't want this drop-down list.

I want to save the record to user Logged-in. (i don't want to choose from the list)

```
// POST: Staffs/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Staff_ID,First_Name,Designation,Department,Employment_Type,Clinic_ID,Title,Middle_Name,Last_Name,DOB,Gender,Marital_Status,Religion,CNIC,Nationality,Hire_Date,Employment_Status,Address,City,Country,Email,Contact_Number,Education,Salary,Leave_Avail,Leave_Details,Loan_Details")] Staff staff)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //db.Staffs.Add(staff);
        //db.SaveChanges();
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        staff.Staff_ID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        db.Staffs.Add(staff);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.Staff_ID = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "ClinicName", staff.Staff_ID);
    ViewBag.Country = new SelectList(db.Countries, "Country_ID", "Country_Name", staff.Country);
    return View(staff);
}
```

My View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Staff_ID, "Staff_ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Staff_ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Staff_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, that's just the default behavior of the scaffold for a one to many. You don't have to use the scaffolded code, and in fact, you're encouraged not to. Second, you've modeled this as a one to many, which it obviously not correct. A "user" is a "staff". Third, that is-a relationship should be your first clue that this is modeled completely incorrectly. That type of relationship implies inheritance. So `Staff` should inherit from `ApplicationUser` as it's simply a more specific type of "user".

The whole reason Identity exists is to provide this level of extension. Otherwise, you could just stick with the profile model of ASP.NET Membership.

Comment: i got it sir, so could you suggest any solution?

Comment: this is 1:1 relationship